# SAS conditionally execute PROC SQL

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, execution

I am building code that imports a daily file of sales from last 30 days, then replaces last 30 days of records in a main table. I want to only replace the last 30 days if the imported daily file has enough records:

```
proc sql;
select min(sale_date) into :oldestSale from daily_sales;
quit;
```

Here's a logic that I want to build in SAS:

> IF oldestSale < (today() - 30) THEN
>       PROC SQL to replace
>   ELSE
>       do nothing
>   END

What would be the best solution? This is trivial in Python which I'm translating this from, but I'm stuck on SAS syntax for doing anything similar...

Comment: Curious, please show us the *trivial* Python code origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'logic' is quite vague in specifics, but the gist seems to be

- import daily sales
- presume daily sales is complete and every daily sale is represented
- if daily sales info starting date is more than 30 days ago

  - remove all sales from main table from starting date
  - append current daily sales

One approach would be to have a macro that peforms the conditional remove/append as a 'replace' action.

```
%macro process_daily_sales;
  proc import … out=daily_sales;
  run;

  %local oldestSale;
  %let oldestSale = %sysfunc(today()); %* sentinel value just in case;

  proc sql;
    select min(sale_date) into :oldestSale from daily_sales;
  quit;

  %local gap;
  %let gap = %eval ( %sysfunc(today()) - &oldestSale );

  %if &gap > 30 %then %do;
    proc sql;
      delete from main_sales where sales_date >= &oldestSale;
    quit;
    proc append base=main_sales data=daily_sales;
    run;
  %end;
%mend;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works except one thing - &oldestSale keeps returning 1.8435E9, and %Eval keeps giving ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required.

Comment: A number that large is probably a datetime value (number of seconds) instead of a date value (number of days). Make appropriate adjustments in the code to handle datetime values instead of date values.

Comment: Used SYSEVALF and it worked. Yes, all dates are stored as datetime values.